# How to communicate between Python and C# using XML-RPC?

Tags: c#, python, xml-rpc

Assume I have a simple XML-RPC service that is implemented with Python:

```py
from SimpleXMLRPCServer import SimpleXMLRPCServer  # Python 2

def getTest():
    return 'test message'

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(('localhost', 8888))
    server.register_function(getTest)
    server.serve_forever()
```

Can anyone tell me how to call the `getTest()` function from C#?

Answer (score 3):

Not to toot my own horn, but: http://liboxide.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/liboxide/trunk/Oxide.Net/Rpc/

```
class XmlRpcTest : XmlRpcClient
{
    private static Uri remoteHost = new Uri("http://localhost:8888/");

    [RpcCall]
    public string GetTest()
    {
        return (string)DoRequest(remoteHost, 
            CreateRequest("getTest", null));
    }
}

static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlRpcTest test = new XmlRpcTest();
        Console.WriteLine(test.GetTest());
    }
}
```

That should do the trick... Note, the above library is LGPL, which may or may not be good enough for you.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for answer, I try xml-rpc library from darin link. I can call getTest function with following code

```
using CookComputing.XmlRpc;
...

    namespace Hello
    {
        /* proxy interface */
        [XmlRpcUrl("http://localhost:8888")]
        public interface IStateName : IXmlRpcProxy
        {
            [XmlRpcMethod("getTest")]
            string getTest();
        }

        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                /* implement section */
                IStateName proxy = (IStateName)XmlRpcProxyGen.Create(typeof(IStateName));
                string message = proxy.getTest();
                MessageBox.Show(message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to call the getTest method from c# you will need an XML-RPC client library. [XML-RPC](http://www.xml-rpc.net/) is an example of such a library.

Comment: dead link ......